# Access denied to pdf file from another server on another domain C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf

The current setup is like this, Server A which hosts the e-service, Server B which is local and internal server. I want to display pdf file in browser in Server A, which Server A will get from Server B.

Now server A is not in the same domain or group as Server B.

when I access server A and type the path in a file browser "\\serverB\folder\file.pdf", I can open it and view it.

When I debug with visual studio then the following code works fine also and views the file:

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + fpath);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(fpath);
Response.Flush();
Response.Clear();
```

where fpath is the path to the file.

However when i try to access it from browser I get the Access is denied error.

I tried Impersonation via the following code:

```
public class Impersonation
{
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
         int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    // Test harness.
    // If you incorporate this code into a DLL, be sure to demand FullTrust.
    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public WindowsImpersonationContext ImpersonateUser(string domain , string user, string pass)
    {
        SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
        try
        {

            // Get the user token for the specified user, domain, and password using the
            // unmanaged LogonUser method.
            // The local machine name can be used for the domain name to impersonate a user on this machine.
            //Console.Write("Enter the name of the domain on which to log on: ");







            // Call LogonUser to obtain a handle to an access token.
            bool returnValue = LogonUser(user, domain, pass,
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                out safeTokenHandle);



            if (false == returnValue)
            {
                int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
            }
            using (safeTokenHandle)
            {



                // Use the token handle returned by LogonUser.
                using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
                {
                    using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
                    {
                        return newId.Impersonate();

                    }
                }
                // Releasing the context object stops the impersonation

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return null;

    }
}

public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
{
    private SafeTokenHandle()
        : base(true)
    {
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
    [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

and used it as this:

```
Impersonation impersonate = new Impersonation();
using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impUser = impersonate.ImpersonateUser("Domain", "User", "Password"))
{
    bool endResponse = false;
    try
    {

        byte[] b = null;
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fpath))
        {
            b = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length);
        }

        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=Report.pdf");
        Response.OutputStream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();

        endResponse = true;


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {

    }
    if (endResponse)
        Response.End();
}
```

It does not retrieve the desired user but the user of Server A instead, but when debugging with visual studio it does work and doesn't throw the error, however when accessing it from web browser it still throws the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's a network related issue for sure. However I've used web services to send pdf file as byte array, and this way it has connected the inner network servers with the DMZ server and I can read my pdf files now.